# Can't get the div to reappear for some reason?

Tags: javascript, html

Im  just messing about with a browser game idea I had but for some reason when I get to my first test , applying damage to the enemy counter , the maths generator somehow stops the fight button reappearing???( See the HaimheadFunction{})

I apologize for the uncleanness of the code , it was just a rough go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>

    var enemy = 100;
    if (enemy > 0 ) {
    document.write(enemy); 

    function fightFunction() {
       document.getElementById('2ndmenu').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('1stmenu').style.display = "none";
    }
    function headsmashFunction() {
       document.getElementById('headsmashmenu').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('2ndmenu').style.display = "none";
    }
    function punchFunction() {
       document.getElementById('punchmenu').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('2ndmenu').style.display = "none";
    }
    function kickFunction() {
       document.getElementById('kickmenu').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('2ndmenu').style.display = "none";
    }
    function HaimheadFunction() {
      document.getElementById('1stmenu').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('headsmashmenu').style.display = "none";
      var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
      document.write(number);

      if (number < 30 ) {
          document.write('damage= 30!');
          enemy = enemy - 100 ;

         document.write(enemy);    
         }
     else{ 
         document.write('you missed'); 

         }

    }
    }
    else{
    document.write('<p> you win! </p>'); 
    }
    </script>
    <div id="1stmenu" style="display: block;">
    <button onclick="fightFunction()">FIGHT</button>
    </div>
    <div id="2ndmenu" style="display: none;">
    <button onclick="headsmashFunction()">Headsmash</button>
    <button onclick="punchFunction()">Punch</button>
    <button onclick="kickFunction()">kick</button>
    </div>
    <div id="headsmashmenu" style="display: none;">
    <button onclick="HaimheadFunction()">AIM FOR HEAD</button>
    <button onclick="HaimbodyFunction()">AIM FOR BODY</button>
    <button onclick="HaimlegFunction()">AIM FOR LEGS</button>
    </div>
    <div id="punchmenu" style="display: none;">
    <button onclick="BaimheadFunction()">AIM FOR HEAD</button>
    <button onclick="BaimbodyFunction()">AIM FOR BODY</button>
    <button onclick="BaimlegFunction()">AIM FOR LEGS</button>
    </div>
    <div id="kickmenu" style="display: none;">
    <button onclick="LaimheadFunction()">AIM FOR HEAD</button>
    <button onclick="LaimbodyFunction()">AIM FOR BODY</button>
    <button onclick="LaimlegFunction()">AIM FOR LEGS</button>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Also consider using jQuery: it greatly simplifies interaction in updating elements inside a DOM and more.

Comment: Yes , i will be using jquery now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using document.write() for your output messages, which destroys all of the html and starts from scratch. Your should have an output `div`, into which you put your output using the `HTMLElement.innerHTML` property.

Here's your code with this change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="output"></div>


<script>

var output = document.getElementById('output');

var enemy = 100;
if (enemy > 0 ) {
output.innerHTML = enemy; 

function fightFunction() {
   document.getElementById('2ndmenu').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('1stmenu').style.display = "none";
}
function headsmashFunction() {
   document.getElementById('headsmashmenu').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('2ndmenu').style.display = "none";
}
function punchFunction() {
   document.getElementById('punchmenu').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('2ndmenu').style.display = "none";
}
function kickFunction() {
   document.getElementById('kickmenu').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('2ndmenu').style.display = "none";
}
function HaimheadFunction() {
  document.getElementById('1stmenu').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('headsmashmenu').style.display = "none";
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
  output.innerHTML = number;

  if (number < 30 ) {
      output.innerHTML += ' damage = 30!';
      enemy = enemy - 100 ;

     output.innerHTML = enemy;    
     }
 else{ 
     output.innerHTML += ' you missed'; 

     }

}
}
else{
output.innerHTML = '<p> You win! </p>'; 
}
</script>
<div id="1stmenu" style="display: block;">
<button onclick="fightFunction()">FIGHT</button>
</div>
<div id="2ndmenu" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="headsmashFunction()">Headsmash</button>
<button onclick="punchFunction()">Punch</button>
<button onclick="kickFunction()">kick</button>
</div>
<div id="headsmashmenu" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="HaimheadFunction()">AIM FOR HEAD</button>
<button onclick="HaimbodyFunction()">AIM FOR BODY</button>
<button onclick="HaimlegFunction()">AIM FOR LEGS</button>
</div>
<div id="punchmenu" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="BaimheadFunction()">AIM FOR HEAD</button>
<button onclick="BaimbodyFunction()">AIM FOR BODY</button>
<button onclick="BaimlegFunction()">AIM FOR LEGS</button>
</div>
<div id="kickmenu" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="LaimheadFunction()">AIM FOR HEAD</button>
<button onclick="LaimbodyFunction()">AIM FOR BODY</button>
<button onclick="LaimlegFunction()">AIM FOR LEGS</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh , okay perfect , ive been away from coding for a good few years so completely forgot this ! Thanks so much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the thing about document.write(x) is that, once a document has been fully loaded, it will rewrite everything in the body of the document - removing all the content already there in the process. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) . Perhaps check out using the element.innerHTML property if you simply want to replace the text in a div!